# Kernel module build fails with "missing argument to -gdwarf-"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto, xilinx, bitbake

I am trying to build a Xilinx XDMA driver for Yocto, using their supplied makefile. When I run my recipe the build fails with the following errors:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 32 KERNEL_SRC=./tmp/work-shared/intel-corei7-64/kernel-source
                 KERNEL_PATH=./tmp/work-shared/intel-corei7-64/kernel-source
                 KERNEL_VERSION=5.10.78-intel-pk-standard CC=x86_64-poky-linux-gcc
                 -fuse-ld=bfd
                 -fmacro-prefix-map=./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0=/usr/src/debug/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0
                 -fdebug-prefix-map=./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0=/usr/src/debug/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0
                 -fdebug-prefix-map=./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/recipe-sysroot= 
                 -fdebug-prefix-map=./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= 
                 -fdebug-prefix-map=./tmp/work-shared/intel-corei7-64/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel LD=x86_64-poky-linux-ld.bfd 
                 AR=x86_64-poky-linux-ar
                 O=./tmp/work-shared/intel-corei7-64/kernel-build-artifacts KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=

Makefile:17: XVC_FLAGS: .
make -C /lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/build
      M=./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/git/linux_driver/xdma modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic'
make[2]: Entering directory './tmp/work-shared/intel-corei7-64/kernel-build-artifacts'
./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/git/linux_driver/xdma/Makefile:17: XVC_FLAGS: .
  CC [M]  ./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/git/linux_driver/xdma/libxdma.o
  CC [M]  ./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/git/linux_driver/xdma/xdma_cdev.o
x86_64-poky-linux-gcc: error: missing argument to '-gdwarf-'
  CC [M]  ./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/git/linux_driver/xdma/cdev_ctrl.o
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic/scripts/Makefile.build:281: ./tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky-linux/xdma-driver-mod/1.0+gitAUTOINC+8d75946900-r0/git/linux_driver/xdma/libxdma.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
x86_64-poky-linux-gcc: error: missing argument to '-gdwarf-'

ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

I have no idea why this happens as it is not something I have specifically enabled. I have searched through the `module.bbclass` file but I couldn't see anything obvious. I believe that something needs to be configured such that the `-gdwarf-` actual ends up being set to a valid value (e.g. `-gdwarf-2` or `-gdwarf-4` etc.)

A grep through the poky repo for dwarf did not reveal anything neither did a search of  `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-40-generic/scripts/`.

My bitbake recipe is as follows:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=441c1ecbc199a036abf37f3aa47c5f34"
    
SRC_URI +=  https://github.com/Xilinx/dma_ip_drivers.git;protocol=ssh;nobranch=1;branch=master"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "8d7594690058dfa828accc02ac81348e416ffe38"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/xdma/linux-driver/xdma"

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "xdma"

inherit module

EXTRA_OEMAKE_task-install:append = " -C ${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR} M=${S}"
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "KDIR=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}"
```

The makefile is the standard one from GitHub. The driver builds correctly for Ubuntu using `make` and I can also build the module if I change my recipe such that it does not include `inherit module`; this change will build the module (`xdma.ko`) but does to install it in the roofs. I am also not sure if `inherit module` includes additional functionality which may be rewired.

How to I either:

1. prevent / disable the `-gdwarf` flag being generated
2. configure the recipe that the `-gdwarf-` resolves to something valid
3. View the actual command being invoked that is causing the issue.

Attempts to build the `xdma.ko` module without the `inherit module` result in an invalid binary being built, i.e. when I try an load the module on the target I get:

```
insmod xdma.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module xdma.ko: Invalid module format
```

Which indicates that the module is compiled from the wrong target.

Answer (score 1):

`inherit module` is required when building kernel modules for Yocto. If it is omitted the build modules is not compatible with the target.

Workaround for the `-gdwarf-` error was to manually write a new makefile which is compatible with Yocto:

```
TARGET_MODULE:=xdma

topdir := $(shell cd $(src)/.. && pwd)

EXTRA_CFLAGS := -I$(topdir)/include

SRC := $(shell pwd)
$(TARGET_MODULE)-objs := libxdma.o xdma_cdev.o cdev_ctrl.o cdev_events.o cdev_sgdma.o cdev_xvc.o cdev_bypass.o xdma_mod.o xdma_thread.o
obj-m := $(TARGET_MODULE).o

all :
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC)

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
    rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
    rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
```

This makefile correctly builds the Xilinx XDMA driver for Yocto. I can confirm that the driver works with Kintex-KC705 FPGA development card.